# Strange collision when calculating p-values in Perl using Statistics::TTest

Tags: perl, statistics

I have a mysterious problem that I can't figure out.

I am using [`Statistics::TTest`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aTTest) to calculate p-values for several thousand pairs of distributions of numbers.

I'm using these p-values to create a [volcano plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volcano_plot_%28statistics%29) and when I plot the p-values I observe a strange artifact where many of the points are getting the same p-value.

After some sleuthing I can re-create the phenomenon with the four pairs of numbers in the code below.

When I calculate p-values for these pairs in Excel the values are all quite distinct (different by several orders of magnitude) but using `Statistics::TTes` I'm getting *exactly* the same value for each pair.

The p-values are very small (around 1.6e-12) so I wonder if this isn't some sort of precision issue but I can't figure it out.

If you run the code below it will display four identical p-values (T-test probabilities, `t_prob`) despite the fact that the true p-values range from `1.7e-19` to `2.8e-29`.

I have tried doing something similar using `Statistics::Distributions` but I had the same problem, however I think `Statistics::TTest` relies on `Statistics::Distributions` for these calculations.

I was not able to find any other modules that perform this calculation.

I should note that the vast majority (99%) of pairs of distributions are getting correct p-values. It's just a handful that produce this strange collision on a wrong value.

Does anyone out there have any insight into what's going wrong?

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Statistics::TTest;

my %datasets = ();


@{$datasets{a}[0]} = (0.722466024,0.925999419,1,1.049630768,1.056583528,1.10433666,1.13093087,1.150559677,1.220329955,1.316145742,1.333423734,1.63691458,1.691534165,0.713695815,0.815575429,0.918386234,0.925999419,0.941106311,0.948600847,0.970853654,0.98550043,0.98550043,1,1.028569152,1.042644337,1.10433666,1.117695043,1.269033146,1.286881148,1.298658316,1.575312331);
@{$datasets{a}[1]} = (-0.49410907,-0.358453971,-0.321928095,-0.286304185,-0.200912694,-0.200912694,-0.168122759,-0.120294234,-0.120294234,-0.104697379,-0.104697379,-0.074000581,-0.058893689,-0.577766999,-0.514573173,-0.514573173,-0.49410907,-0.358453971,-0.358453971,-0.304006187,-0.251538767,-0.184424571);

@{$datasets{b}[0]} = (-0.434402824,-0.286304185,-0.251538767,-0.058893689,-0.043943348,-0.043943348,0.084064265,0.163498732,0.23878686,0.23878686,0.310340121,0.839959587,0.879705766,-0.556393349,-0.268816758,-0.251538767,-0.152003093,-0.104697379,-0.089267338,-0.029146346,-0.029146346,0,0.070389328,0.084064265,0.097610797,0.124328135,0.137503524,0.189033824,0.189033824,0.214124805,0.214124805,0.214124805,0.321928095,0.333423734,0.367371066,0.40053793,0.411426246,0.443606651,0.516015147,0.669026766,0.713695815);
@{$datasets{b}[1]} = (0.782408565,0.799087306,0.82374936,0.887525271,0.925999419,0.933572638,0.956056652,0.97819563,0.98550043,1.021479727,1.084064265,1.097610797,1.13093087,1.150559677,1.15704371,1.176322773,1.182692298,1.22650853,1.286881148,1.292781749,1.310340121,1.459431619,1.485426827,1.521050737,1.59454855,1.695993813,1.713695815,1.726831217,0.40053793,0.411426246,0.59454855,0.925999419,0.941106311,0.948600847,0.98550043,1.028569152,1.070389328,1.117695043,1.124328135,1.220329955,1.316145742,1.744161096);

@{$datasets{c}[0]} = (-0.043943348,-0.029146346,-0.01449957,0.028569152,0.097610797,0.124328135,0.176322773,0.201633861,0.263034406,-0.862496476,-0.104697379,0.084064265,0.084064265,0.084064265,0.124328135,0.124328135,0.163498732,0.263034406,0.275007047,0.286881148,0.321928095,0.333423734);
@{$datasets{c}[1]} = (-2.64385619,-2.556393349,-2.473931188,-2.395928676,-2.395928676,-2.395928676,-2.321928095,-2.321928095,-2.321928095,-2.251538767,-2.251538767,-2.184424571,-2.120294234,-2,-0.535331733,-1.64385619,-1.556393349,-1.514573173,-1.514573173,-1.473931188,-1.434402824,-1.434402824,-1.395928676,-1.395928676,-1.395928676,-1.395928676,-1.358453971,-1.358453971,-1.358453971,-1.358453971,-1.358453971,-1.321928095,-1.286304185,-1.286304185,-1.286304185,-1.251538767,-1.217591435,-1.120294234,-1);

@{$datasets{d}[0]} = (0.933572638261024,0.948600847493356,0.948600847493356,0.970853654340483,0.978195629681652,1.111031312388740,1.150559676575380,1.416839741912830,0.731183241572200,0.790772037862000,0.815575428862573,0.855989697308481,0.871843648509318,0.895302621333307,0.933572638261024,0.941106310946431,0.948600847493356,0.956056652412403,0.970853654340483,0.992768430768924,1.000000000000000,1.063502942306160,1.226508529808680,1.269033146455240,1.298658315564520,1.704871964456350);
@{$datasets{d}[1]} = (-0.473931188332412,0.028569152196771,0.042644337408494,0.056583528366368,0.070389327891398,0.084064264788475,0.097610796626422,0.111031312388744,0.454175893185802,0.454175893185802,-0.514573172829758,-0.268816758427800,-0.168122758808327,-0.136061549576028,-0.043943347587597,0.014355292977070,0.111031312388744,0.124328135002202,0.137503523749935,0.176322772640463,0.238786859587116,0.250961573533219,0.344828496997441);


foreach my $dataset (sort keys %datasets) {

    my $ttest = new Statistics::TTest;
    $ttest->load_data(\@{$datasets{$dataset}[0]},\@{$datasets{$dataset}[1]});
    print "$dataset - t_prob:\t$ttest->{t_prob}\n\n";

}
```

EDIT:  I have not figured out what's going on with Statistics::TTest or Statistics::Distributions, but I have found another module that works correctly.  In case someone else runs into this problem, I'll post it here.  As I understand it, a one-way ANOVA on a single pair of distributions is equivalent to an Student's T-test.  As such, I tried using Statistics::ANOVA and I had success.  Using the definitions of %datasets from the above code, the following loop will calculate correct p-values (matching the values that Excel gives):

```
foreach my $dataset (sort keys %datasets) {

    my $aov = Statistics::ANOVA->new();

    $aov->load( "$dataset\1", \@{$datasets{$dataset}[0]} );
    $aov->add( "$dataset\2", \@{$datasets{$dataset}[1]} );

    $str = $aov->anova(independent => 1, parametric => 1, ordinal => 0);

    print $str->{_stat}->{p_value} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that above Statistics::ANOVA almost perfectly replicates the p-value down to 18 digits of precision, but will deviate after this. Was using paired test (independent => 0) and compared to Excel function =ttest(array1,array2,2,1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64-bit platform there is a chance you may gain something by installing a 64-bit perl, but this question is probably best addressed to the authors of the modules.

[`Statistics::TTest`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aTTest) is written by [Yun-Fang Juan](https://metacpan.org/author/YUNFANG)

[`Statistics::Distributions`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDistributions) is written by [Michael Kospach](https://metacpan.org/author/MIKEK)

Comment: I have tried to mail `Michael Kospach` but his given email address is invalid. I suggest the `Statistics::Distributions` module is unreliable as it hasn't been updated since 2003.

Comment: In S::D description is said that '... can also calculate the upper probability (5 significant digits)' I wonder whether precision might be an issue here indeed?